# "Optional type '(() -> Bool)?' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead" in delegate function call

Tags: swift, function, delegates, boolean, protocols

My goal is to return a bool value of a function in a different class. The error is claiming the function is optional, but I don't understand how it's optional. I even tried to force unwrap it, but it gives me the error "'() -> Bool' is not convertible to 'Bool'".

I have my protocol in ManageCaptureVC file above the class declaration:

```
protocol ManageCaptureVCDelegate: class {
    func selectedInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape() -> Bool
}
```

My defined delegate in my ManageCapture class:

```
weak var delegate: ManageCaptureVCDelegate?
```

And my if statement to try to check the bool value:

```
if self.delegate?.selectedInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape {
/*code*/
}
```

The original function in the delegate class is:

```
func selectedInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape() -> Bool {

    if(selectedInterfaceOrientation == interfaceOrientations.landscapeLeft ||
        selectedInterfaceOrientation == interfaceOrientations.landscapeRight){
        return true
    }

    return false

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function, not reference the function.

Change:

```
if self.delegate?.selectedInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape  {
```

to:

```
if self.delegate?.selectedInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape()  {
```

But since you are using optional chaining, it should be:

```
if self.delegate?.selectedInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape() ?? false {
```

Comment: or declare it as a property: `var selectedInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape: Bool {get}`

Comment: omg I'm an idiot. I've been stuck on this for an hour. How did I not see that!!

Comment: Note that for `var foo: Bool?` you can also use the syntax "if foo == true`. It works because a nil optional is not == true, but an optional that contains a value can be compared to true.